# Chrome ignores url argument and specified geometry

Tags: linux, google-chrome, console

So I believe this is a two part question. The first is that when I use a console command to open google-chrome in a new window, it ignores the url I pass to it. It instead opens a new blank window above my active session.

The second is that the new window ignores my attempts to resize it with wmctrl.No change in size or location takes place.

```
function get_window_id() {
window_id=$(wmctrl -l | grep "$1" | tail -1 | cut -f1 -d" ")
} 

google-chrome --new-window "http://google.com"&
sleep 1
get_window_id google-chrome
wmctrl -i -r "$window_id" -e 0,0,0,1000,1000
```

I get the following errors when I attempt to run this script:

```
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
Created new window in existing browser session.
Cannot convert argument to number.
```